# Swagger api using NodeJS and promise-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, swagger, bluebird

I want to change postgress connection to mysql connection for swagger developed in nodejs.

```
var promise = require('bluebird');

var options = {
  // Initialization Options
  promiseLib: promise
};

var pgp = require('pg-promise')(options);
var connectionString = 'postgres://postgres:admin@localhost:5432/puppies';
var db = pgp(connectionString);
```

I want to use promise-sql to make connection with mysql

var promise = require('bluebird');

var options = {
  // Initialization Options
  promiseLib: promise
};

```
var mysql = require('promise-mysql')(options);

var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'admin',
    database: 'test'
}).then(function(conn){
    // do stuff with conn
    conn.end();
});
```

It triggers error requires(...) is not a function. so, I removed (options). but, it is not connecting database. getting 500 internal server error. Please help me out

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What are you looking for?

Comment: Hi, @MustafaMamun, can you give a short brief on swagger using nodejs and mysql

Comment: NodeJS is a technology built on JS for doing back-end development, Swagger is a technology to document the APIs and Mysql is a database. You create API using NodeJS, Document them using swagger and you save and retrieve data from mysql database.

Comment: `pg-promise` approach to initializing the database is proprietary, you shouldn't expect the same from other libraries. Instead, you should follow the documentation for that `promise-mysql` library.

Comment: @vitaly-t. Could you provide me any reference to understand the issue.